# Is the sentence "The glasshouse has gone and in its places is a water feature." grammatically legitimate?

Tags: grammar

**Question.** Is the sentence "The glasshouse has gone and in its places is a water feature." grammatically legitimate?

**My Attempt.** I tried to put the sentence on search engine but found nothing. To me, I feel that it has no problem when I read it. But I am really unsure about whether it has no grammar issue in a serious way; specifically the subject for the "is" seems to be missing.

Comment: "in its places" should be "in its place".

Comment: In effect, _a water feature_ is the subject of _is_.

Comment: Many thanks for both of you. I got it.